# What is the verbal association to the following picture?

Tags: knowledge, visual, lateral-thinking

My first puzzle of this type. In the following visual design the hidden clues will lead you to the final verbal association. It is only one word.

[image]

Hint 1

> It has no musical connections (just to prevent people from converging on this otherwise creative path)

Hint 2

> If you'd allow me to modify the image to show irrelevant changes. It doesn't change the reasoning or the answer.

Hint 3

> Following Hint 2, don't prioritize to interpret the missing parts, but rather focus on what you can really see,  to gather as many clues as possible.

Hint 4

> The word you can't see (I mean the final solution) can't be "maple", just for the same reason as it can't be "marie", or " varied". Maybe a later hint will clarify this if you don't see what I mean.

Hint 5

> Leaf colors have been already mentioned. Is that all?

Hint 6

> I did something to the question that the answer hardly does, everybody here wants a part of the question.

Hint 7

> Someone requested a hint(/clarification) that describes what was guessed right or wrong. I will try to be as clear as possible. Right(1): The lines refer to letters. Right(2): those letters are the letters of "maple". Right(3): Leaf/Leaves is a relevant remark Right(4): The different coloring is deliberate and important. Wrong: everything else. My advice was: the "cutout" parts are *not* informative, the visible parts *are* informative.

Hint 8

> How many different shapes do you see?

Comment: I see what I can't see. But I'm afraid that the `knowledge` tag will stop me from going further.

Comment: WhatsUp, just ignore that tag, it's not that overspecific. Of course access to internet won't do any harm.

Comment: One thing nobody seems to have commented on yet is that rot13(gur jbeq NYR vf pbybherq qvssreragyl jvguva gur jbeq ZNCYR (be jungrire vg vf)) - this could be important, although I don't yet see the answer myself...

Comment: Do the compression artifacts have any significance?

Comment: Minor significance (if this isn't an oxymoron)

Comment: rot13(Ybbxf yvxr fbzr fbeg bs cvr gung unf cvrprf (znlor rira n yrggre) rngra bhg bs vg. Ohg, V'z abg tbvat gb nafjre ntnva...)

Comment: You say it "obviously" isn't maple, but almost everyone here thought the word was maple, so it isn't obvious at all to us, and your hints haven't really explained why it should be obviously something else.  I think you should give a hint that either confirms or denies MacGyver88's theory that consonants are dark green and vowels are light green.  That would give us something tangible to work with.

Comment: I meant it is not even a word, what you see (I hope this is obvious). What the lines refer to is another thing, and many people guessed it right. The coloring is also important, but the lighter ones are not A, I, E as in MacGyverr88' s answer. I deleted the last hint until I can come up with a more appropriate one.

Comment: The only thing I saw many people guess was that the cutouts were musical notes, but your Hint 1 said there were no musical connections.  If many people guessed something right, I think you should state it in a hint because I, for one, have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 10):

New guess:

> **VARIEGATED**

Reasons:

> 1. OP said the answer was a single word.
>  2. The word *could* be "MAPLE" and there is a variegated maple tree, which  has leaves of multiple colors, like the letters.
>  3. If the consonants are dark and the vowels are light, the letters shown could instead be "VARIE".  (from MacGyver88)
>  4. The title implies there is a letter or word you can't see (also from Macgyver88), meaning there could be the invisible word "GATED" at the end.

Old guess:

> **Cutleaf maple**

Reasoning:

> The word "maple" is spelled using leaf colored letters -> "leaf maple", and then parts of it are cut out -> "cut leaf maple".

Comment: If you took the cutout parts by themselves they appear to spell Wii... I wonder if that's just a coincidence?

Comment: @postmortes I don't see it.  I could see the musical notes thing maybe, but I don't see the W in Wii.  If anything, I thought maybe instead of musical notes the cutouts were hockey sticks -> Toronto Maple Leafs, but OP hasn't commented on my answer at all so I haven't changed it.

Answer (score 8):

Is it

> [Autumn Leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autumn_Leaves_(1945_song))? (something you can't see, as per title, because you *hear* it instead)

The word seems to be a yellow and green

> MAPLE (suggesting the colours its **leaves** have in the **autumn**)

with some parts missing. A couple of the missing parts could have been caused by cutting off a very specific shape, and that shape would fit the other spots too:

> [image]

Comment: Not the intended answer. Ignore the main title in  terms of searching clues. The  musical notes are interesting. (Some of the notes are not filling preceeding holes, so not _that_ specific)

Answer (score 6):

I’m thinking it’s

> The **Maple Leaf Rag**
>
>   The first step is to realize that the completed word is “Maple”. The next step is to realize that the text is colored like leaves. Finally, as noted in [Bass’ answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91025/63153), the missing shape is a musical note. Putting it all together, the final answer can be deduced.
>  Edit: As a cheeky little side note, the Maple is in pretty bad shape - you could even say it’s *ragged*

Alternatively,

> (taking things literally), what I see is a **Maple split** or **Split Maple**. Unfortunately, still more than one word, but at least it's an idea that could be worked with.

Comment: I should have specified that the conclusion is one word. The musical connections are interesting in both answers. The cheeky side note is a good one.

Comment: About that music, rot13(Gur Ragregnvare naq Gur Zncyr Yrns Ent ner gjb pbzcyrgryl qvssrerag pbzcbfvgvbaf ol Fpbgg Wbcyva.)

Comment: I saw it after I googled it too:)I think he google searched it too, but a bit more superficially

Comment: @Archipelago Actually, I'd played one or the other on the piano a long time ago, and had gotten them confused together by now. Will go ahead and fix it

Comment: Wow.. I only listened to them on youtube after seeing your answer

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be the word

> maple

But since the vertical lines are removed it leads me to think that perhaps it is a

> striped maple

However, given that the poster indicated that the answer is a single word, and given that one smart contributer showed that perhaps the missing sections are

> Musical Notes

Then a quick Google search on the three leads me to

> the band Striped Maple Hollow

And so the part of that answer that according to the title of the puzzle is unseen would be the word

> Hollow.

Comment: Promising start, but it seems not only the vertical parts are missing. Perhaps there is more to it...

Comment: Promising start indeed, and yes there is more to it.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is

> DESICCATE

Reason being

> Desiccate - to dry thoroughly; dry up.

Moreover

> Online I found a tree called an incised silver maple (desiccated silver maple). (oops - was actually dissected silver maple) but it lead me to this conclusion regardless) :) It has 5 lobes on its leaf. In the picture, the removed portions are mostly vertical, which may represent the veins of the leaf where water is carried, keeping the leaf hydrated. Without the veins, the leaf would dry up, or break apart.

Previous answers were

> Camouflage, VARIED and MARIE - but those answers were incorrect.

Because

> The one I can't see or the answer has been hidden behind some dark and light green shapes that look like maple leaves but aren't. So, it must be camouflaged. - Patterns- Dark letters are consonants, Light letters are vowels - Leaving either "EE", a really long "E", or an "IE". The one I can't see is the ending "D" . Also,the picture or word within has been altered from the original. So it is varied. *Note - VARIES probably should qualify as well.* Also, Marie Curie is famous for helping to find radioactivity which is usually depicted by a green color but can't really be seen visually. Also the word appears to be decaying(radioactive decay). She also died due to complications from radiation exposure during her life.

Comment: You got off the right track. Try not to "guess" (I know it's easy to say). Regarding the plus's rot13(
lbh znqr gjb creprcgvbaf gung ranoyrf zr gb fnl gung gjb pyhrf unir orra qvfpbirerq)

Comment: You always say something interesting, but remain very superficial. "Camouflaged"/masked/changed to what? :) Also, you started to go in a right direction Hint5 refers to.

Comment: Hint 5 and 8 refer to the same thing, you realized correctly. But veins? This is a far association, unnecessary. If you ask me, start looking for more obvious things first.

Comment: @Archipelago, If you hadn't noticed, things are a lot more obvious to the person who already knows the answer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I chose the wrong word. Not "obvious", just "something closer"

Comment: @Archipelago, no problem. I'm just a little sensitive. rot13(Fb, lrfgreqnl zbeavat V sbhaq fbzrguvat bayvar 6 cneg 2 gung unf gur fnzr cnggrea naq pbybef. V jbhyq whfg yvxr gb xabj vs V nz tbvat va gur pbeerpg qverpgvba?)

Comment: rot13(Uzz. V qba'g guvax fb . TB gb guvf qverpgvba: funcrf, pbybef, cynagf, cnegf , Uvag6, Uvag7..

Comment: rot13(Bxnl, gura gung'f rkgerzryl pbvapvqragny.) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answer/guess:

> FOREST

Reasoning:

> You can't see the FOREST from the TREES.

Comment: Unfortunately no:) Although this one has the clearest and most unique concept so far:) I think I commented somewhere that ignore the title, it is not a source of clues, maybe I should have written this right under the title:)